# What decides when cron.hourly runs?

Tags: cron

For some reason my cron.hourly is executing at 17 minutes past the hour. The number of seconds past 00:17 is seemingly random.

Why would it execute at 17 and not at 00? Is there a way to set this? Is it always going to be 17 or will that vary from day to day or month to month?

Answer (score 17):

`cron.hourly`, `cron.daily` and friends are probably started from the system's main crontab in `/etc/crontab`. For example, in Debian, the relevant line is this:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

The idea behind *not* running exactly on the hour is to make the load spikes from multiple cron jobs less sharp. `cron.daily` jobs are started at another minute, so the hourly and daily jobs don't start at the same time. And if users set their own cron jobs to run on the hour, at least these will not start at the same time. In most housekeeping-type jobs the exact time of running doesn't matter.

Comment: You are correct! I now see that the actual cron jobs that I add when doing crontab -e are actually located in /var/spool/cron.

How do I edit those that are in the main crontab file? man says I am supposed to use crontab -e but when I do that none of the run-parts commands show up :( 

Should I just manually edit /etc/crontab instead? For example if I want to change it from 17 past the hour to on the hour precisely?

Comment: @Rahman, I've always just edited it, but then, I don't always go by the book... That said, I think the `crontab` utility just edits the per-user crontabs, so I don't think you have a choice but to edit manually. (`crontab` would do some sanity checks before actually saving the file.)